# Use regular expression to hide database information stored in an array

Tags: php, regex

I have to show source code, but want to remove database information. The info is stored this way

```
'db.host' => 'localhost',
'db.user' => 'user',
'db.pass' => 'pass',
'db.name' => 'name
```

right now I got this as regex, but it doesnt seem to work

```
$content = preg_replace('\'db.host\' => \'(.*)\'/', '', $content);
```

Error:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Unknown modifier '='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the string properly, try this

```
$content = preg_replace("/'db.[a-z]+' => '(.*?)'/i", '', $content);
```

Have a look at my example: http://regexr.com?36js6

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the first forward-slash (opening [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)).

```
$result = preg_replace('/\'db.host\' => \'(.*)\'/', '', $subject);
                        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$s = <<< EOF
'db.host' => 'localhost',
'db.user' => 'user',
'db.pass' => 'pass',
'db.name' => 'name'
EOF;
echo preg_replace("~(=>\s*')[^']+'~m", '$1****\'', $s);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'db.host' => '****',
'db.user' => '****',
'db.pass' => '****',
'db.name' => '****'
```